# Am I using promises correctly?

Tags: node.js, promise, q

I have the following function (I'm using the `Q` promise library):

```
confirmEmail: function(confirmationCode){
    var deferred = q.defer();

    User.find({
      where: {confirmation_code: confirmationCode}
    }).then(function(user){
      if(user){
        user.updateAttributes({
          confirmation_code : null,
          confirmed: true
        }).then(function() {
          deferred.resolve();
        });
      }else{
        deferred.reject(new Error('Invalid confirmation code'));
      }
    });

    return deferred.promise;
  }
```

I've been reading a bit about the best practices regarding promises e.g. [What is the explicit promise construction antipattern and how do I avoid it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-deferred-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it)
http://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html

Have I written the above function so that it is keeping with these practices, or is there a better way?

Comment: Just wondering - what was unclear in the example here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-deferred-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me like you can rewrite your method to this:

```
confirmEmail : function(confirmationCode) {
  return User.find({
    where : { confirmation_code : confirmationCode }
  }).then(function(user) {
    if (! user) {
      throw new Error('Invalid confirmation code');
    }
    return user.updateAttributes({
      confirmation_code : null,
      confirmed         : true
    });
  });
}
```

Both `User.find()` and `user.updateAttributes()` seem to be returning promises (I'm inferring this from your code), so you can easily create a promise chain with them.

But even if they weren't returning promises, you probably wouldn't have needed `q.defer()`, as outlined [on this page you already mention](http://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html) (*"Rookie mistake #4"*). See [`Q.Promise`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#qpromiseresolver).

Comment: I'm not sure about the control flow. The confirmEmail method is returning the User.find promise, so if you call a `then()` on it, you'll get the result of that promise, and not on the `user.updateAttributes` one

Comment: @Qualcuno: No, `confirmMail` returns the *result of calling `.then()`* on the `User.find()` promise, so it's a promise that resolves with the result of `user.updateAttribute()`.

Comment: @Bergi I understand! what about the fact that rejections aren't handled in  user.updateAttributes?

Comment: @Qualcuno: Right, rejections of `updateAttributes()` would be promoted here. To match the original code, one would have to add `.catch(ignoreError)` (although I don't hink that's a good idea).

Comment: @Qualcuno error handling is left to the caller of `confirmMail()`. I specifically didn't ignore any errors on `user.updateAttributes()`—which is what the original code was doing—because it seemed like an oversight and not intentional.

Answer (score 0):

With Mongoose (especially from version 4), promises are supported natively, so you don't need to use Q. Also, on Node.js 0.12+ and io.js there's natie support for Promises, so again no need for Q!

This is how I would write the method (using the native Promise; here a [polyfill](https://github.com/taylorhakes/promise-polyfill) if still on Node 0.10)

```
confirmEmail: function(confirmationCode){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        User.find({
            where: {confirmation_code: confirmationCode}
        })
        .then(function(user) {
            if(user){
                user.updateAttributes({
                    confirmation_code : null,
                    confirmed: true
                })
                .then(resolve, reject)
            }
            else {
                reject(new Error('Invalid confirmation code'))
            }
        }, reject)
    })
}
```

How it works:
1. The confirmEmail method returns one Promise. As per pattern, the promise can be either `resolve()`'d or `reject()`'d
2. User.find is invoked. With Mongoose, that returns a promise, so you can do: `then(callback, reject)`. So, if User.find returns an error, the Promise returned by confirmEmail will be rejected (the "outer one").
3. If User.find succeeds, we proceed. If there is no result (`if(user)` is false), then we manually reject the "outer promise" and we don't do anything else.
4. If there's a user, instead, we call `user.updateAttributes`, which too returns a promise. We're thus invoking `then(resolve, reject)` so the result of that promise will be passed to the "outer promise".

Example use:

```
obj.confirmEmail(confirmationCode).
.then(function(user) {
    // Everything went fine
}, function(error) {
    // This is invoked if: User.find() failed, or if no result was obtained (with the error "Invalid confirmation code") or if user.updateAttributes failed
})
```

Comment: That's just the [very same antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572) as the OP uses.